# SQL Query to find missing entries

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables:

**Applications**

- id
- reviewer1_id
- reviewer2_id

**Reviewers**

- id

**Reviews**

- id
- application_id
- reviewer_id

(*Note that I removed the table columns that are irrelevant, such as name, title, etc.)

Reviewers are assigned multiple applications, and submit 1 review for each application.  So, an application should have 2 reviews associated with it, both from different reviewers.

I need to write a MySQL query to select all reviewers that have not yet completed reviews for each application to which they're assigned.

I've been working at this problem for quite a while, but the solution is eluding me.  I can find all reviewers associated with applications that have not received any reviews yet, but if an application has only 1 review but not the other completed, I'm at a loss.

Comment: Provide sample data and desire output. please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
     And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: So I can understand how to write better questions, would it be good to provide tables directly in the question containing sample data and desired output?  Would those tables replace the description of the database I included?  Thank you!

Comment: You should provide all 3 things, db schema, sample data and desire output. Also you can use a sqlFiddle so you get a real test. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1a2cc/3. But that wont should replace the text in the question because sometimes is down. The schema make clear when a field is a date or a string for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correct. You assign `Reviewer` on the `Application` first. And when `Reviewer` finish the review appear on `Reviews`

So you need use `LEFT JOIN` to find what reviews arent complete.

```
SELECT A.id, reviewer1_id
FROM Applications A
LEFT JOIN Reviews R
       ON A.reviewer1_id = R.reviewer_id
      AND A.id = R.application_id
WHERE R.id IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT A.id, reviewer2_id
FROM Applications A
LEFT JOIN Reviews R
       ON A.reviewer2_id = R.reviewer_id
      AND A.id = R.application_id
WHERE R.id IS NULL
```

If you also neeed `Reviewer` name will need one aditional `JOIN`

```
SELECT A.id, A.reviewer1_id, RV.name
FROM Applications A
LEFT JOIN Reviews R
       ON A.reviewer1_id = R.reviewer_id
      AND A.id = R.application_id
     JOIN Reviewers RV
       ON A.reviewer1_id = RV.id
WHERE R.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  You are correct in your understanding of the problem.  I just had to change one line: `ON A.reviewer2_id = R.reviewer_id` and it worked great.

Comment: Fixed, do you like this format using `UNION`?, in this case if one Application miss boths reviews you will get two rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Applications a 
JOIN Reviewers r1 ON a.reviewer1_id = r1.id
JOIN Reviewers r2 ON a.reviewer2_id = r2.id
LEFT JOIN Reviews rv1 ON r1.id = rv1.reviewer_id
LEFT JOIN Reviews rv2 ON r2.id = rv2.reviewer_id
WHERE rv1.id IS NULL OR rv2.id IS NULL
```